# Hybrid charger and NVDC charger

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, batteries, buck-boost

I have some questions about the battery chargers.
Here are my questions,

1.) Could someone explain the Narrow Voltage DC charger, I try to google it, but I am still very confused.

2.) In what situation do I need to use NVDC charger?

3.) In the Narrow Voltage DC charger, why the Vsys voltage should be equal to battery voltage? why I cannot use buck-boost to get more high voltage?

[image]

Comment: In this particular architecture there is no buck-boost converter between the battery and the system. You could design a charger where there was one, but that would be a different architecture.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, the buck-boost is between the sys and adapter, not the battery.

Comment: @user253751 do you know these three question I asked?